# site not serving php page

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, cpanel

SOLVED

The users have filled out the form on another PC and B.php has been served up. There must have been an issue with the users' PC.
Sorry to have wasted people's time.
I have a database based site using php and mysql on a Linux shared server which I manage using CPanel.

I have a page  `A.php` which calls `B.php` using a form.

Recently two users have had a 404 message for B.php when they submit the form on `A.php`. There is no evidence of the 404 in the CPanel error log.

I have searched for a solution on Google and here, but can’t find a solution.

Any tips on how to debug this would be appreciated.

I've extracted the form component of the page which calls B.php I didn't include in my original question as it's long; a 20 X 11 radio button form.

This form has worked hundreds of times, but persistently fails for one user

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="InsertNewRating.php" method="post" name="myForm2 ">
    <table id="ratingsInput">
    <tr class "toprow" w">
        <td align="right">
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>Low</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            High
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class "col1" 1" align="left">
            <strong>Attribute</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            2
        </td>
        <td>
            3
        </td>
        <td>
            4
        </td>
        <td>
            5
        </td>
        <td>
            6
        </td>
        <td>
            7
        </td>
        <td>
            8
        </td>
        <td>
            9
        </td>
        <td>
            10
        </td>
        <td>
             N/A
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #CCC; height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
            A1
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A0" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A0" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A0" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A0" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A0" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A0" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A0" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A0" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A0" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A0" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A0" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #C0C0C0;height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
            A2
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A1" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A1" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A1" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A1" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A1" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A1" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A1" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A1" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A1" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A1" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A1" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #CCC; height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
            A3
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A2" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A2" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A2" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A2" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A2" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A2" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A2" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A2" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A2" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A2" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A2" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #C0C0C0;height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A4
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A3" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A3" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A3" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A3" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A3" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A3" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A3" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A3" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A3" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A3" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A3" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #CCC; height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A5
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A4" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A4" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A4" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A4" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A4" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A4" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A4" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A4" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A4" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A4" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A4" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #C0C0C0;height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A6
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A5" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A5" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A5" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A5" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A5" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A5" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A5" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A5" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A5" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A5" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A5" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #CCC; height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A7
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A6" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A6" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A6" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A6" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A6" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A6" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A6" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A6" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A6" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A6" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A6" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #C0C0C0;height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A8
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A7" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A7" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A7" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A7" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A7" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A7" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A7" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A7" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A7" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A7" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A7" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #CCC; height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A9
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A8" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A8" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A8" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A8" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A8" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A8" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A8" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A8" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A8" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A8" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A8" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #C0C0C0;height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A10
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A9" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A9" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A9" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A9" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A9" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A9" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A9" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A9" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A9" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A9" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A9" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #CCC; height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A11
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A10" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A10" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A10" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A10" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A10" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A10" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A10" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A10" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A10" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A10" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A10" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #C0C0C0;height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A12
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A11" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A11" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A11" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A11" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A11" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A11" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A11" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A11" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A11" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A11" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A11" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #CCC; height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A13
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A12" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A12" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A12" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A12" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A12" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A12" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A12" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A12" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A12" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A12" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A12" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #C0C0C0;height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A14
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A13" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A13" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A13" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A13" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A13" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A13" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A13" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A13" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A13" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A13" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A13" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #CCC; height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A15
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A14" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A14" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A14" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A14" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A14" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A14" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A14" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A14" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A14" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A14" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A14" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #C0C0C0;height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
            A16
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A15" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A15" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A15" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A15" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A15" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A15" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A15" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A15" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A15" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A15" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A15" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #CCC; height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A17
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A16" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A16" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A16" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A16" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A16" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A16" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A16" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A16" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A16" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A16" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A16" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #C0C0C0;height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A18
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A17" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A17" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A17" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A17" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A17" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A17" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A17" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A17" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A17" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A17" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A17" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #CCC; height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A19
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A18" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A18" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A18" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A18" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A18" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A18" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A18" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A18" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A18" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A18" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A18" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #C0C0C0;height:30px">
        <td class="Col1" align="left">
             A20
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A19" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A19" value="2"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A19" value="3"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A19" value="4"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A19" value="5"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A19" value="6"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A19" value="7"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A19" value="8"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A19" value="9"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A19" value="10"/>
        </td>
        <td class="otherCols">
            <input type="radio" name="A19" value="11"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" id "smallbutton" n" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show some code? We can't do anything with just this information.

Comment: Can you post some code? It helps greatly to solve your issue. Without it we have almost no way of finding the problem.

Comment: Sounds like B.php is not getting loaded because the form submission is not satisfying a condition?

Comment: Thanks to MHakvoort, Caleb Kleveter and Hexana for looking at this